# Markov chains, limiting distribution and periodicity

Tags: probability, markov-chains

My textbook on Markov chains has theorems on when a chain has a unique limiting distribution, but not the other way around, i.e. when a chain does *not* have a limiting distribution. My question is the following:

If a Markov chain $\{X\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is irreducible, positive recurrent and periodic, can one say for certain that a limiting distribution does not exist?

Comment: For *some* initial distributions, yes one can say that.

Comment: Okay, thanks. If the chain is periodic, can one always find an initial distribution such that a limiting distribution does not exist?

Comment: Yes, this is what my first comment states. If you ask how to find such an initial distribution, try some distribution concentrated on a periodicity class.